# Retrieve Email Information from .EML Files

Tags: c#, email, sharepoint

I have a .eml files. What I want to do is to retrieve the From, To, Subject, Body & attachments(if any) from this .eml file and save to database. 
I need to do that in C# and without any third party applications.

I searched for some source code, but couldn't find any, except this [Is it possible to read .eml files in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151155/is-it-possible-to-read-eml-files-in-net) 
But there is no source code, which is more helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Refer Following link **urgently**:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76607/Easily-Retrieve-Email-Information-from-EML-Files-R

```
protected CDO.Message ReadMessage(String emlFileName)
{
    CDO.Message msg = new CDO.MessageClass();
    ADODB.Stream stream = new ADODB.StreamClass();
    stream.Open(Type.Missing, ADODB.ConnectModeEnum.adModeUnknown, ADODB.StreamOpenOptionsEnum.adOpenStreamUnspecified, String.Empty, String.Empty);
    stream.LoadFromFile(emlFileName);
    stream.Flush();
    msg.DataSource.OpenObject(stream, "_Stream");
    msg.DataSource.Save();
    return msg;
}
```

You can also get help for elm parsing from:

http://blog.onderweg.eu/2010/12/parsing-eml-files-in-c/

This is also useful tutorial:

http://www.emailarchitect.net/eagetmail/kb/csharp.aspx?cat=18

Comment: CDO seems to be deprecated and not supported anymore... any newer ideas? (Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6179413/2216555)