# How Can I use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook library to read .eml file using C#?

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop, com-interop

I am using this code to read .msg file in C#

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

var item = app.Session.OpenSharedItem("MSG_FILE_PATH") as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem;

string body = item.HTMLBody;
```

How can I use the same library to read .eml file?

Comment: There are many solutions in google. Just google it.

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29439/Easily-Retrieve-Email-Information-from-EML-Files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my tests, the Outlook function "OpenSharedItem" just only used to open iCalendar appointment (.ics) files, vCard (.vcf) files, and Outlook message (.msg) files. For the eml file, I think you can refer to the following code:

```
protected CDO.Message ReadMessage(String emlFileName)
{
   CDO.Message msg = new CDO.MessageClass();
   ADODB.Stream stream = new ADODB.StreamClass();
   stream.Open(Type.Missing, ADODB.ConnectModeEnum.adModeUnknown,        
   ADODB.StreamOpenOptionsEnum.adOpenStreamUnspecified, String.Empty, String.Empty);
   stream.LoadFromFile(emlFileName);
   stream.Flush();
   msg.DataSource.OpenObject(stream, "_Stream");
   msg.DataSource.Save();
   return msg;
}
```

More information for this: [Retrieve Email Information from .EML Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16013254/retrieve-email-information-from-eml-files)

Thanks,

Simon