# Is it Possible to Reply From an .EML file?

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I would like to know if it is possible to open and reply as a `response message` on top of a saved `.eml` file using C#? 
If yes, are there any guides that I can follow?

I am able to do so with `EWS` `EmailMessage` where the message resides in Inbox. However, due to requirements, I am required to retrieve and reply from a saved `.eml` file instead of replying from the email in Inbox directly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't do this using the EWS reply operations because EWS is a Server side API while using the EWS Managed API you using Client side library that just instrumenting the SOAP call to the backend whenever an action is taken.  You can temporary import the EML back in the server https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-import-items-by-using-ews-in-exchange and then you reply and then delete the Message again if don't want it to exist. If your want to send using EWS you didn't want to import the message use something like mimekit to generate the MIME of the response message offline http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Frequently-Asked-Questions.htm then you can just sent the Mime generated by mimekit via EWS.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could achieve this, by first opening the EML file (please see this question and answer):

[Retrieve Email Information from .EML Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16013254/retrieve-email-information-from-eml-files)

And then when you have the contents of the message in code, copy the data over to whatever email-sending API you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:-
Click the message options menu in the top right corner of the message. Select Save email.

Step 2:-
Save the file. The file name will default to the subject line of the email, with special characters removed. Your download options depend on whether you're using Front on the web or in the desktop app:

*Web: Your file automatically saves to wherever you have it set up in your browser settings (like your Downloads folder)

*Desktop app: You will get the “Save As” prompt where you can rename the file and choose your download location

Step 3:-
You will see your .eml file in your chosen location. You can attach it to a message via drag-and-drop or with the attachment file picker.

Comment: The question is tagged `c#` so one can assume the author wants to do this programatically...?